# React and accepted standards

Tags: reactjs, components

Perhaps not the best place to ask this question.  If not, please point me down the trail I need to go.

I've started working with ReactJS to freshen up programming vernacular and I believe I have the hang of the principle concepts; however, while learning a new programming language I have found MANY MANY different ways to do things (such as the case with computer programming).  I have a simple input component I want to use in my design:

```
class TextField extends Component{
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.state = {errmsg: ''}
    this.setError = this.setError.bind(this);
  }
  setError(errormessage){
    this.setState({
      errmsg: errormessage
    })
  }
  render(){
    var inpdiv = this.props.id + "_div";
    var errdiv = this.props.id + "_err";
    return(
      <div id={inpdiv}>
        <label for={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}
          <input type="text" id={this.props.id} name={this.props.id} />
          <div id={errdiv}>{this.state.errmsg}</div>
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default TextFieldest;
```

Notice the setError function.  I call this function from another (parent) component:

```
class Form extends Component{
  constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context)
    this.emailaddress_ref = React.createRef();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    this.emailaddress_ref.current.setError('Testing the Error Area of the Test Component');
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Test id="emailaddress" ref={this.emailaddress_ref} label="Enter Email Address" />
        <Button btntext="Press Me!" handleclick={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Form;
```

My question is:
Is this the most accepted way to handle changing the state of a child component or am I going down a bad path here?

Answer (score 0):

You might rather want to pass down the error function via props, since it decouples one component from another, and it doesnt lead to a point where if you render two or more components you will have a mess handling refs in secenarios where you really dont need them. refs are rare in their need, and while you can bend them your way, its much saner to just send things via props. In general using ids for reusable components either is not a great idea.

You will need to realize in your case for example who should handle the error and to what extent. Is you text input semi autonomous with regards to input validation? If you reuse is elsewhere will you believe that its validation should be handled by parent? Both yes and no are valid answers, but you need to understand who owns the flow in your app.

Comment: Abraham, your answer is appreciated and makes excellent sense; however, I have not found my way into passing a prop to a child function to trigger a state change.  Can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Basically state really should chnage only on merits of the component itself contained behavior. Having a prop (prone to change by design) to alter state will lead to possible circular references and mulltiple re-renders. If there is really a need for that you could perform it on the render method prior to return. But thats not really desirable.

Comment: To further elaborate in your example, if your text input component has a self validation behavior, it should be trigger in a, say focus out event, which would run validation and if it passes, it would send a message upwards to alter state, otherwise it would change its state as invalid and not send anything above..